# Cast LINQ object as to another LINQ class

Tags: c#, windows, linq, t-sql

In SQL database I have two tables, TablleA and TableB.

`TableA` abstract is:

```
Column1 int IDENTITY(1,1),
Column2 varchar(30),
Column3 money
```

`TableB` has identical schema but inverted identity as follows:

```
Column1 int IDENTITY(-1,-1),
Column2 varchar(30),
Column3 money
```

For my querying purposes in SQL I union those two tables and retain unique record identity.
Now, in my C# winform application I have following methods.

```
private void DisplayContent(TableA tableObjectToDisplay)
private TableA FindRecord(int recordIdentity)
```

Since `TableA` and `TableB` LINQ class schemas are identical, rather than writing methods to find and display `TableB` class objects, (with body identical to existing methods), I would prefer to reuse methods that utilize `TableA` class.

One way would be to alter my existing methods to accept and return `object` class values, test the type and cast accordingly within each methods. Property names remain the same so code could be reused. However, I find it a bit barbaric to take this route.

Is there any way to cast one LINQ class object as another LINQ class object?
Is there a common interface LINQ object bound to same database inherit from that I could use instead of barbaric `object`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a LINQ class - do you mean Entity Framework?

Comment: If you're _only_ reading data you could create a view that does the `UNION` for you and bind that to a single class using EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct casting isn't going to work since the language is statically typed.  Even if the classes are *exactly the same* in structure, there's no way for the compiler to know or guarantee that.

Are the types auto-generated?  Usually that involves `partial` classes, so you can define an interface and make use of the `partial` classes to implement that interface.  Something like this:

```
interface ISomething
{
    int Column1 { get; }
    string Column2 { get; }
    decimal Column3 { get; } // or whatever the type is for money, I don't remember
}
```

Then add partial classes to accompany the generated partial classes.  Something like this:

```
partial class TableA : ISomething
{
    // The interface is already implemented in the generated code
}

partial class TableB : ISomething
{
    // The interface is already implemented in the generated code
}
```

That should allow your common code to accept instances of `ISomething` (hopefully more aptly named, of course) rather than `TableA` or `TableB` specifically:

```
private void DisplayContent(ISomething tableObjectToDisplay)
```

Comment: not only was it smart and simple, it also allowed me to cast interfaced objects! Turned out a bit more complicated because of matching property types - LINQ to SQL uses some lees-than-commonly used types in place of primitive types.